# Cannot update Smart Groups after upgrade to 5.6.1

Tags: smartgroups

After upgrading to 5.6.1, I've discovered that the option to edit the smart group search is missing.

Steps:

1. Contacts->Manage Groups
2. Click on Settings beside a group
3. At bottom of screen in 5.6.0 there were the options:

   - Contacts in this group
   - Edit Smart Group Criteria

As shown below:

[image: Edit Smart group exists]

But in 5.6.1 the option isn't displayed:

[image]

Is this a bug introduced in 5.6.1?

Comment: no idea but have asked in the post-release chat room at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev-post-release

Comment: definitely seeing it on dmaster which suggests no regression (or short lived if it was) https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/group?reset=1&action=update&id=6

Comment: the link above is a to a smartgroup i created there which has the 'Edit Smart Group criteria' link on its Settings screen

Comment: I CAN see that link on a smart group (that I created) on my own copy of master so it's something about the group rather than a code change - I couldn't find a way to 'break ' the group

Comment: clear templace_c diretory and rebuild your cache '/civicrm/menu/rebuild'

Answer (score 0):

In 5.6 I experienced problems with smart groups. When I upgraded to 5.6.1 they disappeared.

I'm looking at my Smart Group settings and all is well.

Try cleaning up your caches and deleting the contents of the templates_c folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have updated any of your overridden Civi files.

Check your logs files and see if anything obvious flags.